# The new duplicate selection UI

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I love that I can check the answer I want to close that someone else found. But can you move the preview below the radiobuttons and shrink it a little bit?

The reason for moving the preview below the radio buttons, is so the users don't have to chase the interface when it pushes the buttons below the preview.

Check out the UI on this question.

Comment: can we have, like, a grace period of say .. at least .. 15 minutes .. between the time we deploy an improvement, and the time the complaints begin?

Comment: No, you may not. The Viking has spoken!

Comment: BTW took a while to find a question with duplicate close and points to two questions and it works great. I actually like this way of voting to close Jeff my good buddy ol pal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pressing enter when editing the title field of a question submits it with no confirmation.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52263/pressing-enter-when-editing-the-title-field-of-a-question-submits-it-with-no-conf)

Comment: @Just testing the UI on your question ... was curious to see how it works

Comment: @waffles no prob.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Did we just got a "drop shadow" effect in the votes-left pop-up?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52260/did-we-just-got-a-drop-shadow-effect-in-the-votes-left-pop-up)

Comment: Added another one, so you can see with two questions.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are criticizing (with viking sanction), can you skip the extra click on "vote to close" when we close as duplicate?

I understand it's necessary for other reasons where you have no confirmation, but it's useless on voting to close (because there's another "screen" where you can click cancel), and I'm trying to cut down on clicks.

Comment: Juan -- we need to make sure you've READ the duplicate. Clicking != reading. Clicking, seeing the post load, then reading it and clicking vote to close, is what is desired here.

Comment: No no @jeff, I meant the first click, the one when you click the radio button "exact duplicate" and _then_ click vote to close (this one is useless), not the one where the duplicate loads

Comment: ah, I see, that makes more sense. I'll try to get that in..

Comment: This has been implemented now. No official announcement, but I noticed it this morning.