# Pressing enter when editing the title field of a question submits it with no confirmation

Tags: feature-request, keyboard, new-questions

So I'm asking this question, written something in this box and tagged it, but I've had a thought I want to change the title. I do so, but hit enter in the process. `----resumed typing-----` So I edit it again to add the rest of what I wanted to say, but in the meantime the question is incomplete and may cut off in the middle of something. (if you look at the first edit of this question, it looks pretty incomplete).

If we could have some sort of confirmation that we really meant "I'm done editing this!" it would completely cure the problem.

Granted there aren't any GOOD reasons we should press enter, but we still may be thinking we're in the main box or in a search engine text field. (same issue happens with retag box and edit summary)

Comment: Well, thankfully, it won't let you submit the question if you fail validation (title too short, body nonexistent, missing required tags on Meta).

Comment: Maybe enter should move focus it to the Body field?

Answer (score -1):

> Granted there aren't any GOOD reasons we should press enter

....

Comment: there aren't good reasons for a new user messing up formatting either. I wouldn't have asked the question if the fix was non-trivial.